# Getting a description of an attribute of a widget in Tkinter using iPython or using help()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a Python Beginner but perhaps there is a simple solution.

In Tkinter you use `widget.button(command=None)` to send commands to the backend.

I've used `help(Button)` and `dir(Button)` and I can see "command" attribute in the widget specific options. I don't know how to reach in further and get information about it.

As far as I've gotten was `help(Button.__init__)` which moves past the button widget and seems to get me closer to the command attribute...

This is kind of a "Feed a man a fish for a day" vs "Teach a man how to fish scenario". If someone can tell me how to do this I can dig through other Python module documentation at any level and learn how to apply them myself.

[command prompt image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW2xd.jpg)

[command prompt image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/le92E.jpg)

[command prompt image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqtvQ.jpg)

[command prompt image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76SVk.jpg)

Comment: Show your [mcve] so we all have context to help you.

Comment: Read [The Tkinter Button Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)

Comment: Tkinter is a bit of an unusual module in the sense that nothing's really being done in Python - the Python code is just a wrapper that forwards operations to the actual GUI implementation in an embedded Tcl/Tk interpreter.  So, there's nothing in the module that actually *knows* what the `command` option does - the only reason that it's mentioned in `help()`'s output at all is that someone manually typed in that text in the docstring for `Button.__init__()`.  There is no further digging you can do from Python, you have to go to external documentation (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook perhaps).

Comment: Thankyou very much, jasonharper, for that. I refused to believe it wasn't possible to find documentation of a module in python help. I'll check the external documentation for the command attribute and post it as an answer to this question!

Answer (score 0):

iPython or `help()` doesn't have the detailed information of all attributes in Tkinter. The details of the command attribute for Button widget in Tkinter were at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm

Thanks to jasonharper for enlightening me!